# Can not silence a mysqli call

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have been trying to convert code over to using mysqli prepared statements ([Converting from mysqli to prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153848/converting-from-mysqli-to-prepared-statements?noredirect=1#comment100845333_57153848)).  I have the following code which I can not silence the error message from the call.  Instead it is spitting out the "PHP Fatal error: ..." which halts the script so the error code is not executing but because the error is spitting out, only the  header is being shown to the user.

Also note, I was attempting to also convert over to using the native php error handling as described by 'Your Common Sense' in the referenced post, but reverted back to the traditional "if (! ...) {...}" style of code due to issues not mentioned by that person (by doing that conversion).  All of these modifications have been reversed that I can see.

Now for the code (and note that there is an intentional misnaming of the DB table to throw an error for checking of the code)...

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Issues2 WHERE id=? AND disabled='0' LIMIT 1";
if (! $PRE = @mysqli_prepare($linkDB, $SQL)) {
    echo "<f><msg>ERROR: Could not prepare query: ".$SQL.", ".mysqli_error($linkDB)."</msg></f>";
} else {
    ...
}
```

I have tried calling the mysqli_prepare() call with and without the prepended '@' symbol, but no luck...  I should be getting the "ERROR: Could not prepare ..." message, but instead I just get the XML header alone.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest actually fixing the issue instead of suppressing it. try/catch blocks are great for catching fatal errors so that you can log them and then clean up as needed.

Comment: Please provide the full error message of the fatal error so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: @aynber  Maybe I'm wrong, but I would say that try/catch blocks are _not_ great for catching fatal errors.

Comment: @PatrickQ Hmm, no, not for fatal errors. The actual error message really would help out here. :/

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_report()` to generate automatic error reports? It probably can't be suppressed with `@` like built-in functions can. You'll need to use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);` to temporarily disable it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, but I think you all missed the sentence "and note that there is an intentional misnaming of the DB table to throw an error for checking of the code".  I am trying to get the code to work so in the event of an actual error of some sort it doesn't show errors and such to the user, but dies in a graceful manor while notifying our staff.

Comment: @Barmar unless mysqli_report() is something enabled by default, no I did not enable it.  I'll try turning it off to see if that does anything...

Comment: @Barmar that worked!  If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  Any idea why this would be on?  Not sure if it is something that got turned on by trying to implement the error checking by 'Your Common Sense' that didn't get turned back off...

Comment: Turns out it was a line that was not commented out from the attempts at using 'Your Common Sense' error handling (which employed a mysqli_report() call).  I have commented it out and all appears to be working as it should.

Comment: As a side note, for anyone coming to this post in the future.  By commenting out the "mysqli_report()" call as suggested by Dharman in the referenced SO link in the OP, the error handling suggested by 'Your Common Sense' works (although it does require a little more code than originally suggested which he says he is updating his website that he referenced).  Just an FYI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

to enable automatic error reporting from `mysqli` functions; otherwise, they just return a falsey value and you have to check for this in your code. Unlike built-in PHP functions, `@` doesn't suppress these error reports.

Use

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
// do stuff with explicit error checking
// ...
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

if you want to temporarily disable this. Or remove the above call if you want to revert to explicit error checking everywhere.